# Unexpected behavior of the bilinear.grid function of the akima package

Tags: r

There is a behavior of the bilinear.grid function of the akima package that I don't understand.
I'm looking to enlarge a matrix like in the example below.

```
my_x = c(1, 5, 20)
my_y = c(2, 9)
my_matrix = matrix(c(1,3, 7, 3, 2, 1), ncol=2)
my_result = akima::bilinear.grid(x=my_x, y=my_y, z=my_matrix, nx=7, ny=3)
my_result2 = akima::bilinear.grid(x=my_x, y=my_y, z=my_matrix, nx=7, ny=3, xlim=c(1, 20), ylim=c(2,9))
```

I expect to get a 7 by 3 matrix, which is indeed the case
For my_result$y I expect to get a vector of 3 elements ranging from 2 to 9. This is indeed the case.
For my_result$x I expect to get a vector of 7 elements ranging from 1 to 20 but I get a vector of 7 elements ranging from 1 to 9 !!!

Same problem with my_result2.

Is this normal?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the solution is the interp package and the bilinear.grid function !